# Banach fixed-point theorem: Prove that given non-linear system has exactly one solution

Tags: real-analysis, nonlinear-system, fixed-point-theorems

**Question:** For $1\leq i, k \leq n$ you are given some real numbers $b_i$ and $c_{ik}$ so that:
$$\sum_{i,k=1}^{n} c^2_{ik} < 1$$
Show, using Banach fixed-point theorem, that the following non-linear system of equations has exactly one solution:

$$x_i = \sum^{n}_{k=1} \sin (c_{ik}x_k) + b_i,  \qquad  1 \leq i \leq n$$

**My progress:** I have to show, that $$d(f(x),f(y)) < q \cdot d(x,y), \quad 0 <q< 1$$
I took the equation and tried to play around with it:
$$\begin{aligned} 
d(f(x), f(y))^2
&= \Big(\sum^{n}_{k=1}\sin(c_{1k}x_k)-\sum^{n}_{k=1}\sin(c_{1k}y_k)\Big)^2 + ...+
\Big(\sum^{n}_{k=1}\sin(c_{nk}x_k)-\sum^{n}_{k=1}\sin(c_{nk}y_k)\Big)^2 \\
&= \Big(\sum^{n}_{k=1}\big(\sin(c_{1k}x_k)-\sin(c_{1k}y_k)\big)\Big)^2+...+\sum^{n}_{k=1}\big(\sin(c_{nk}x_k)-\sin(c_{nk}y_k)\big)\Big)^2 \\
&= \bigg(\sum^{n}_{k=1}2\sin\Big(\frac{c_{1k}(x_k-y_k)}{2}\Big)\bigg)^2 + ... + \bigg(\sum^{n}_{k=1}2\sin\Big(\frac{c_{nk}(x_k-y_k)}{2}\Big)\bigg)^2\end{aligned}$$

Then I could use $(z_1+z_2+...+z_n)^2 \leq n \sum c_{ik} (z^2_1+z^2_2+...+z^2_n)$ to show that it contracts, since $\sum c_{ik} <1$, but I can't evaluate it without knowing what $n$ is... Feel out of options. Any help strongly appreciated!

Comment: How did you go from the differences of $\sin$s to a single $\sin$? How does that help you?

Comment: @copper.hat Well, it didn't help me. I used the $\sin a - \sin b$ formula in hope of getting something close to the z-inequality I wrote below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be given by $\phi(x)_i= \sum^{n}_{k=1} \sin (c_{ik}x_k) + b_i$.

\begin{eqnarray}
|\phi(x)_i - \phi(y)_i| &=& \sum^{n}_{k=1} |\sin (c_{ik}x_k) -\sin (c_{ik}y_k)| \\
&\le& \sum^{n}_{k=1} |c_{ik}||x_k-y_k| \\
&\le& \sqrt{\sum^{n}_{k=1} c_{ik}^2}\|x-y\|
\end{eqnarray}
I used the mean value theorem and Cauchy Schwartz above.

Hence
$\|\phi(x)-\phi(y)\| \le \sqrt{\sum^{n}_{i,k=1} c_{ik}^2 } \|x-y\| $

Comment: I understand the point, but in my function each summand is a sum in itself. Did I miss something?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Using your methods, I end up with equation looking like this: https://imgur.com/a/njZWFrV. I have a sum of sums, so to say. Hope I made it more clear.

Comment: How did you drop the squares on the $c_{i,k}$ on the last line of your picture?

Comment: I forgot them in a rush.

Comment: Yes, I guess? Looks like I do have it... I'm still thinking whether I correctly evaluated the sums...

Comment: I don't see how you moved the square inside in the second last line of your picture.